# R aggregate by large number of columns

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame (df) that has about 40 columns, and I want to aggregate using a sum on 4 of the columns. Outside of the 4 I want to sum, each unique value in column 1 corresponds to identical values across the rest of the columns, and I want to keep all the columns in the aggregated data frame. Is there any way I can specify the columns in the by = list() portion without having to type them all explicitly? For example, if I knew I wanted to sum column "field" by columns 1-36. I've tried

```
aggregate(df$field, by = list(df[,1:36]), FUN = sum)
```

but it throws an error since that isn't a list of names. I've also tried

```
aggregate(df$field, by = list(names(df)[1:36]), FUN = sum)
```

And while this doesn't give an error, it gives me back an aggregation with my df names as the unique observations.

Or am I missing an easy way to say "aggregate these four columns using the rest of the data frame?"

Thanks

Here's an example data frame:

```
  A B C D Sum
1 A B C D   1
2 A B C D   2
3 A B C D   3
4 E F 1 R   4
5 E F 1 R   5
```

After I aggregate I want it to look like:

```
  A B C D Sum
1 A B C D 6
2 E F 1 R 9
```

I know I can do this if I explicitly state x$A, x$B, x$C, x$D in the "by" portion of the aggregate statement, but in my actual data frame this would require explicitly typing about 40 field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking how to aggregate the sum of multiple variables, grouped by the remaining variables. I would do this by combining the multiple variables first and then aggregating using the (in my opinion) more convenient formula interface of the `aggregate` function. For instance, consider aggregating the sum of Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, and Petal.Length in the iris dataset based on the remaining variables (Petal.Width and Species):

```
agg <- iris
cols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")
agg$sum <- rowSums(agg[,cols])
agg <- agg[,!names(agg) %in% cols]
aggregate(sum~., data=agg, FUN=sum)
#    Petal.Width    Species   sum
# 1          0.1     setosa  47.8
# 2          0.2     setosa 284.1
# 3          0.3     setosa  68.1
# 4          0.4     setosa  74.6
# 5          0.5     setosa  10.1
# 6          0.6     setosa  10.1
# 7          1.0 versicolor  79.9
# 8          1.1 versicolor  34.3
# 9          1.2 versicolor  63.8
# 10         1.3 versicolor 166.5
# 11         1.4 versicolor  96.7
# 12         1.5 versicolor 136.5
# 13         1.6 versicolor  42.0
# 14         1.7 versicolor  14.7
# 15         1.8 versicolor  13.9
# 16         1.4  virginica  14.3
# 17         1.5  virginica  27.4
# 18         1.6  virginica  16.0
# 19         1.7  virginica  11.9
# 20         1.8  virginica 162.2
# 21         1.9  virginica  71.7
# 22         2.0  virginica  91.3
# 23         2.1  virginica  94.4
# 24         2.2  virginica  48.3
# 25         2.3  virginica 125.6
# 26         2.4  virginica  44.4
# 27         2.5  virginica  48.2
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the example data mentioned by @josilber, this would be another option to achieve the desired output using `dplyr()` *which is more efficient for huge datasets*

```
library('dplyr')

out = agg %>% 
regroup(lapply(names(select(agg, -sum)), as.symbol)) %>% 
summarise_each(funs(sum))

Source: local data frame [27 x 3]
Groups: Species

#  Species Petal.Width   sum
#1      setosa         0.1  47.8
#2      setosa         0.2 284.1
#3      setosa         0.3  68.1
#4      setosa         0.4  74.6
#5      setosa         0.5  10.1
#6      setosa         0.6  10.1
#7  versicolor         1.0  79.9
#8  versicolor         1.1  34.3
#9  versicolor         1.2  63.8
#10 versicolor         1.3 166.5
#..        ...         ...   ...
```

using `data.table`

```
library('data.table')

out = setDT(agg)[, list(sum = sum(sum)), by= names(agg[,!"sum", with=FALSE])]

#  Species Petal.Width   sum
#1:     setosa         0.2 284.1
#2:     setosa         0.4  74.6
#3:     setosa         0.3  68.1
#4:     setosa         0.1  47.8
#5:     setosa         0.5  10.1
#6:     setosa         0.6  10.1
#7: versicolor         1.4  96.7
#8: versicolor         1.5 136.5
#9: versicolor         1.3 166.5
#10:versicolor         1.6  42.0
# ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the data.frame method (`aggregate.data.frame`) like this:

```
aggregate(df["field"], by = df[1:36], FUN = sum)
```

or use the formula method (`aggregate.formula`) like this:

```
nms <- c("field", names(df)[1:36])
aggregate(field ~., df, sum)
```

In terms of the example data at the end of the question:

```
Lines <- " A B C D Sum
1 A B C D   1
2 A B C D   2
3 A B C D   3
4 E F 1 R   4
5 E F 1 R   5"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)

# data.frame method
aggregate(df["Sum"], df[1:4], sum)

# data.frame method - alternative
aggregate(df[5], df[-5], sum)

# formula method
aggregate(Sum ~., df, sum)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, it's just that the first person to post essentially had the same thing. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This would be the current answer with dplyr:

```
library('dplyr')
mytb<-read.table(text="
A B C D Sum
1 A B C D   1
2 A B C D   2
3 A B C D   3
4 E F 1 R   4
5 E F 1 R   5", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

mytb %>% 
  group_by_at(names(select(mytb, -"Sum") ) )  %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs=sum)
```